# Shifting a column down by one

Tags: r, dataframe

Say I have a `data.frame` that looks like this

```
 df <- data.frame(AAA = rep(c(NA,sample(1:10, 1)),5),
  BBB = rep(c(NA,sample(1:10, 1)),5),
  CCC = rep(c(sample(1:10, 1),NA),5))

> df 
   AAA BBB CCC
1   NA  NA  10
2    3   7  NA
3   NA  NA  10
4    3   7  NA
5   NA  NA  10
6    3   7  NA
7   NA  NA  10
8    3   7  NA
9   NA  NA  10
10   3   7  NA
```

I want to shift column CCC down by one so that all the numbers align in a single row, and then delete the rows that contain no data (often every other row - BUT NOT ALWAYS - the pattern might vary through the `data.frame`.

Comment: If you want us reproduce this exact result, you need to use `set.seed`

Comment: @DavidArenburg can you also move a column up?  For example, how could I move the BBB column up one level?  I have not been able to modify your previous code.

Comment: You can move it using `transform(df, BBB = c(BBB[-1], NA))`. With `dplyr` you can move up/down with `lag` and `lead`. For example, `library(dplyr); transform(df, BBB = lead(BBB))`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a combination of the very efficient `transform` and `na.omit` functions

```
df <- na.omit(transform(df, CCC = c(NA, CCC[-nrow(df)])))
```

Answer (score 25):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
mutate(CCC=lag(CCC)) %>%
na.omit()
```

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
na.omit(setDT(df)[, CCC:=c(NA, CCC[-.N])])
```

Answer (score 4):

You can shift everything down by one with:

```
df['CCC'] <- c(NA, head(df['CCC'], dim(df)[1] - 1)[[1]])
```

To delete rows with only `NA` values, do:

```
df <- df[apply(df, 1, function(x) !all(is.na(x))), ]
```