# Shift values in single column of dataframe up

Tags: r, dataframe

Using example data like this:

```
example=data.frame(x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), y=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), z=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))
```

which looks like this:

```
    x   y   z
1   1   1   1
2   2   2   2
3   3   3   3
4   4   4   4
5   5   5   5
6   6   6   6
7   7   7   7
8   8   8   8
```

I would like to shift all values in the z column upwards by two rows while the rest of the dataframe remains unchanged.
The result should look like this:

```
    x   y   z
1   1   1   3
2   2   2   4
3   3   3   5
4   4   4   6
5   5   5   7
6   6   6   8
7   7   7   NA
8   8   8   NA
```

I only found ways to move the values of a column down, or a shifting of the whole dataframe.

Any ideas? 
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shifting a column down by one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25687727/shifting-a-column-down-by-one)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your problem simplifies to:

- Drop the first `n` elements in a vector
- Pad `n` values of `NA` at the end

You can do this with a simple function:

```
shift <- function(x, n){
  c(x[-(seq(n))], rep(NA, n))
}

example$z <- shift(example$z, 2)
```

The result:

```
example
  x y  z
1 1 1  3
2 2 2  4
3 3 3  5
4 4 4  6
5 5 5  7
6 6 6  8
7 7 7 NA
8 8 8 NA
```

Comment: Or `c(tail(x, -n), rep(NA, n))`. This question has a very bad smell of a duplicate...

Comment: but what is the data.table solution!

Comment: @rawr, sharp as always :)

Comment: @Andrie Thanks again for the help. I have been trying to utilize this to achieve a shift in the other direction (two NA values in row 1 and 2, followed by the initial series) but couldn't figure out how to do this. Can you help me out?

Comment: @Andrie could you modify to work for multiple columns, with different shifts. Say column 1 you wanted to remain original, but column 2 you wanted to shift up 1 position/row, then column 3 you want to shift up 2 positions... column 4 up 3 positions etc...

Answer (score 10):

```
example = tibble(x=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), 
                   y=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), 
                   z=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))

example %>% mutate_at(c("z"), funs(lead), n = 2 )

# A tibble: 8 x 3
      x     y     z
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  1.00  1.00  3.00
2  2.00  2.00  4.00
3  3.00  3.00  5.00
4  4.00  4.00  6.00
5  5.00  5.00  7.00
6  6.00  6.00  8.00
7  7.00  7.00 NA   
8  8.00  8.00 NA
```

Comment: How can this code be used to shift rows instead of columns ?

Comment: per `dplyr` documentation: `Warning message: funs() is deprecated as of dplyr 0.8.0....`  i made the following slight-update, and it works fine: `example %>% mutate_at(c("z"), tibble::lst("z"=lead), n = 1)`

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't find a good duplicate, so here's another solution using `length<-`

```
shift2 <- function(x, n) `length<-`(tail(x, -n), length(x)) 
# or just shift2 <- function(x, n) c(tail(x, -n), rep(NA, n))
transform(example, z = shift2(z, 2))   
#   x y  z
# 1 1 1  3
# 2 2 2  4
# 3 3 3  5
# 4 4 4  6
# 5 5 5  7
# 6 6 6  8
# 7 7 7 NA
# 8 8 8 NA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
## In case you want to shift your rows down by one step for only one column
`z <- example$'z'`

# Deleting the last z value in order to shift values 
# ahead by one period to realign with other rows

z_1 <-head(z,-1)

# We set the initial z value to zero

for (i in 1: (length(z)+1)) {
  if(i != 1){
    z[i] = Z_1[i-1]}
  else{
    z[i] = 0
  }
}
Z
# Append Z to dataframe
example$z <- z
```

Comment: This is essentially a less efficient version of the accepted answer, replacing the vectorized operation with a for loop.

Answer (score -2):

This function in the 'useful' package moves columns in both direction:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/useful/versions/1.2.6/topics/shift.column

Comment: It is better to give an explanation or at least summarize an explanation directly into your answer than point to an URL without further help.