# R: create column with the values of another column -1

Tags: r, dataframe, dataset

I have a table in R containing **n** values. I want to create a column **B**, which has the values of another column **A**, but moved them "up" 1 line:

Example:

```
A    B
_    _
1    2
2    3
3    n
n    n
```

I know that the first item of **A** will be deleted in column **B** and also I would like to duplicate the value **n** and move it to the last "empty" spot of **B** (which would otherwise be 0 because I moved all values "up")

Comment: With `dplyr`, `df %>% mutate(B = lead(df$A))`. Add `%>% tidyr::fill(B)` if you like, though `NA` seems more useful than `"n"`.

Comment: @Max This is already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25995257/r-shift-values-in-single-column-of-dataframe-up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dat <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2, 3, 4))
dat$B <- dat$A[c(2:length(dat$A), length(dat$A))]
```

Should work.

Comment: @lmo thanks, I misread it. Assumed he wanted the first value to jump over to the end. Updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
df1$B <- with(df1,c(tail(A,-1),tail(A,1)))
```

Sample data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(A = c(1, 2, 3, 0))
```

Output:

```
#> df1
#  A B
#1 1 2
#2 2 3
#3 3 0
#4 0 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply replace the values with

```
table$B[1:n-1] <- table$A[2:n]
```