# Shift values in single column of dataframe UP with lag specified in another column

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to adjust the prices from different countries to one time zone, which means shifting a column up by lag declared in another column (shift is the time difference).

Using example data like this:

```
example=data.frame(country=c("IT","IT","GR","GR","GR","TR","TR","TR","TR"), 
                   price=c(200,150,300,480,590,638,237,438,555), 
                   shift=c(0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2))
```

which looks like this:

```
        country   price   shift
        IT        200     0
        IT        150     0
        GR        300     1
        GR        480     1
        GR        590     1
        TR        638     2
        TR        237     2
        TR        438     2
        TR        555     2
```

I want to get the following result:

```
        country   price   shift
        IT        200     0
        IT        150     0
        GR        480     1
        GR        590     1
        GR        NA      1
        TR        438     2
        TR        555     2
        TR        NA      2
        TR        NA      2
```

I tried to use a solution from this thread:
[R: Shift values in single column of dataframe UP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25995257/r-shift-values-in-single-column-of-dataframe-up)
but since it uses a one value of lag, is not fully applicable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Using `dplyr::lead`*

```r
library(dplyr)

example %>% 
  group_by(shift) %>% 
  mutate(price = lead(price, unique(shift)))
```

*or using `data.table::shift`*

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(example)[, price := shift(.(price), type = "lead", n = shift), .(shift)][]
```

*giving*

```
#>   country price shift
#> 1 IT        200     0
#> 2 IT        150     0
#> 3 GR        480     1
#> 4 GR        590     1
#> 5 GR         NA     1
#> 6 TR        438     2
#> 7 TR        555     2
#> 8 TR         NA     2
#> 9 TR         NA     2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea relying solely on base R functions,

```
example$new_price <- unlist(lapply(split(example, factor(example$country, levels = unique(example$country))), 
                                   function(i) { i1 <- unique(i$shift); 
                                                 i2 <- c(tail(i$price, (nrow(i) - i1))); 
                                                 c(i2, rep(NA, i1)) }))
```

which gives,

> ```
>   country price shift new_price
> 1      IT   200     0       200
> 2      IT   150     0       150
> 3      GR   300     1       480
> 4      GR   480     1       590
> 5      GR   590     1        NA
> 6      TR   638     2       438
> 7      TR   237     2       555
> 8      TR   438     2        NA
> 9      TR   555     2        NA
> ```