# Shifting rows up in a particular column of data

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a question about shifting of rows in the particular column of a data.

```
data <- data.frame(B=c(NA,NA,0,NA,NA,0),C=c(1,NA,NA,1,NA,NA))
   B  C
1 NA  1
2 NA NA
3  0 NA
4 NA  1
5 NA NA
6  0 NA
```

I tried from this post [Shifting a column down by one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25687727/shifting-a-column-down-by-one)

```
na.omit(transform(data, B = c(NA, B[-nrow(data)])))
```

but only get

```
  B C
4 0 1
```

expected output;

```
  B  C
1 0  1
2 0  1
```

How can we achieve that ?

Thanks.

Comment: @RonakShah - I imagine `data.frame(lapply(data, na.omit))` might be better as it won't coerce everything to the same type.

Comment: What are you wanting to do if there are unequal numbers of valid cases in each column?

Comment: `na.omit(transform(data, C = c(NA,NA, C[-((nrow(data)-1):nrow(data))])))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove all `NA` from each column and do not care that the rows will not match between columns you can do:

```
data <- data.frame(B=c(NA,NA,0,NA,NA,0),C=c(1,NA,NA,1,NA,NA))

res<-lapply(data,function(x){x[complete.cases(x)]})
res<-data.frame(res)
```

the second line says: for every column in `data` keep only the values which are not `NA`

Thanks to @thelatemail for the correction from the solution below, which worked, but would have kept the columns as factors:

<s>data <- data.frame(B=c(NA,NA,0,NA,NA,0),C=c(1,NA,NA,1,NA,NA))</s>

res<-apply(data,2,function(x){x[complete.cases(x)]})

Comment: Thanks! OTH, all column values returning as factors! How to solve that?

Comment: This is less than ideal. There's almost no need to ever do `apply(df,2,...)` as it coerces to a matrix instead of retaining the `data.frame` structure. Use `lapply(df, ....)` instead and convert back to a data.frame, which will not bulldoze any `factor` attributes.