# How to create new value based on date values in R

Tags: r, date

I have a big data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'), Date = c("01-Feb-17", "05-Feb-17", "03-May-17","24-May-17","20-Oct-17", "25-Oct-17"), Name=c("John", "Jack", "Jack", "John", "John", "Jack"), Workout=c('150', '130', '140', '160', '150', '130'))
```

How to create a new value (Average_Workout) that will contain the average value of "Workout" for each period of time since the beginning of the year.

For example,

[image]

Answer (score 3):

We can use `cummean` after grouping by 'Name'

```
library(dplyr)
res <- df %>%
         #if not ordered by 'Date' 
         #arrange(Name, as.Date(Date, "%d-%b-%y")) %>%
         group_by(Name) %>%
         mutate(Avg = cummean(Workout))

as.data.frame(res)
#  id      Date Name Workout      Avg
#1  1 01-Feb-17 John     150 150.0000
#2  2 05-Feb-17 Jack     130 130.0000
#3  3 03-May-17 Jack     140 135.0000
#4  4 24-May-17 John     160 155.0000
#5  5 20-Oct-17 John     150 153.3333
#6  6 25-Oct-17 Jack     130 133.3333
```

NOTE: When we quote a `numeric` element, it is going to be `character` or `factor` class depending on whether `stringAsFactors = FALSE` or `TRUE`

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(id = c('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'), 
  Date = c("01-Feb-17", "05-Feb-17", "03-May-17","24-May-17","20-Oct-17", "25-Oct-17"), 
  Name=c("John", "Jack", "Jack", "John", "John", "Jack"), 
  Workout=c(150, 130, 140, 160, 150, 130), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Is it possible to shift column Avg down by one for Names? For example, Avg value move from 01-Feb-17 (John) to 24-May-17 (John). And I want to do this for every Name and delete then NA. I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25687727/shifting-a-column-down-by-one but it isnt the same what I want. Could you help me please?

Comment: @Denis Did you meant `df %>%  group_by(Name) %>% mutate(Avg = lag(cummean(Workout)))  %>% na.omit`

Comment: I mean delete new value (Avg) with NA