# Removing NAs from two columns in data frame a shift up

Tags: r, dataframe, whitespace, na

I have this data frame

```
                               atac.v1.pbmc.5k.possorted.bam.bam possorted.bam.bam
chr1.9941.10736                                 NA                NA
                                             13196              4348
chr1.10918.11476                                NA                NA
                                              2624               658
chr1.20874.21591                                NA                NA
                                               652               343
```

and I would like to remove the NAs and get this:

```
                               atac.v1.pbmc.5k.possorted.bam.bam possorted.bam.bam
chr1.9941.10736                              13196              4348                 
chr1.10918.11476                             2624               658                  
chr1.20874.21591                             652                343
```

There are many questions about removing NAs, but I couldn't manage to use any of them to do this. I tried remove NAs and various code to remove white spaces, but wasn't able to.

Comment: Please insert your programming language as a tag. Also, provide a sample of your dataset using the `dput()` function as it is not clear how your dataframe is structured

Comment: There are potentially various ways of solving this. However, the dataframe's structure is unclear, as @RicS says. Please clarify this so that people can help.

Comment: Hi both, after I put dput(df) i get this ```

Answer (score 0):

For R a similar question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25687727/shifting-a-column-down-by-one).

Thus when you want to solve it in R you can eg. use the following:

```
df = data.frame('name'=c('a',NA,'b',NA), 'val'=c(NaN, 1, NaN, 5))
library(dplyr)
na.omit(transform(df, name = lag(name)))
```

The df is only given to have a minimal running program.

Comment: The problem is I don't want to delete rows, I want to delete NAs, then shift the values up beneath them. These are the real values corresponding the row names. Once these are deleted and shifted up, then I would like to delete the empty row to leave the desired data frame above.